# Angularjs show div if other two are not available inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following table code,

`LT.leaveTrainingData` contains all the data

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="userList in LT.leaveTrainingData.users"> 
            <td class="tdDataColumn"  ng-repeat="daysList in LT.leaveTrainingData.days">
                <div class="cursPointer" ng-click="LT.userLeaveUpdate(userList.userID,userList.userName,daysList.date,matrixData.leaveType)" 
                    ng-repeat="matrixData in LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData" 
                    ng-class="{tdBlue: matrixData.leaveType == 'PO',
                                 tdGreen: matrixData.leaveType == 'PH',
                                 tdRed: matrixData.leaveType == 'TC'}"
                    ng-if="daysList.leaveType != 'NP' 
                            && daysList.leaveType != 'SD' 
                            && daysList.leaveType != 'SH' 
                            && daysList.leaveType != 'O' 
                            && matrixData.userID == userList.userID 
                            && daysList.date == matrixData.date">&nbsp;
                </div>  
                <div  
                    ng-class="{tdBlue: daysList.leaveType == 'O',
                                 tdYellow: daysList.leaveType == 'SD',
                                 tdOrange: daysList.leaveType == 'SH',
                             tdGrey: daysList.leaveType == 'NP'}"
                    ng-if="(daysList.leaveType == 'NP' 
                        || daysList.leaveType == 'SD' 
                        || daysList.leaveType == 'SH' 
                        || daysList.leaveType == 'O')">&nbsp;
                </div> 
                <div class="cursPointer">
                    1
                </div>
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If the `td` has no child div then we have to show the third `div` with the value of 1.  Otherwise no need to show. It means first two has some conditions it the condition succeed the colors class will be shown. If the first two `div` fails to show the we have to show the third `div` with the value of 1. Please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Well, this is damn simple. Just move your `ng-if` logic to a scope function and call it there:</strike>

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="userList in LT.leaveTrainingData.users">
            <td class="tdDataColumn" ng-repeat="daysList in LT.leaveTrainingData.days">
                <div class="cursPointer"
                     ng-click="LT.userLeaveUpdate(userList.userID,userList.userName,daysList.date,matrixData.leaveType)"
                     ng-repeat="matrixData in LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData"
                     ng-class="{tdBlue: matrixData.leaveType == 'PO',
                                 tdGreen: matrixData.leaveType == 'PH',
                                 tdRed: matrixData.leaveType == 'TC'}"
                     ng-if="shouldShowFirstDiv(userList, daysList, matrixData)">&nbsp;
                </div>

                <div
                    ng-class="{tdBlue: daysList.leaveType == 'O',
                                 tdYellow: daysList.leaveType == 'SD',
                                 tdOrange: daysList.leaveType == 'SH',
                             tdGrey: daysList.leaveType == 'NP'}"
                    ng-if="shouldShowSecondDiv(daysList)">&nbsp;
                </div>

                <div class="cursPointer" ng-if="shouldShowThirdDiv(userList, daysList, matrixData)">
                    1
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the JS:

```
// Name it properly, I'm just using it for simplicity
$scope.shouldShowFirstDiv = function (userList, daysList, matrixData) {
    return daysList.leaveType != 'NP'
            && daysList.leaveType != 'SD'
            && daysList.leaveType != 'SH'
            && daysList.leaveType != 'O'
            && matrixData.userID == userList.userID
            && daysList.date == matrixData.date;
};

$scope.shouldShowSecondDiv = function (daysList) {
    return daysList.leaveType == 'NP'
            || daysList.leaveType == 'SD'
            || daysList.leaveType == 'SH'
            || daysList.leaveType == 'O';
};

$scope.shouldShowThirdDiv = function (userList, daysList, matrixData) {
    return !$scope.shouldShowFirstDiv(userList, daysList, matrixData) && !$scope.shouldShowSecondDiv(daysList);
};
```

I miss understood the example. I guess, you can just solve it using the CSS:

```
.cursPointer {
     display: none;
}

td .cursPointer:only-child {
      display: block;
}
```

Comment: provide a working example to reproduce this problem. This is pretty straightforward

Comment: we are not repeating `matrixData` in third div. so it is always null. when i include ng-repeat `matrixData`, its showing wrong.

Comment: Oh correct @satheesh. I've updated the answer. Check if that works

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (though not tested it) ??

```
  <div class="cursPointer" ng-if="!(daysList.leaveType == 'NP' 
                                    || daysList.leaveType == 'SD' 
                                    || daysList.leaveType == 'SH' 
                                    || daysList.leaveType == 'O') && (!LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData || (LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData && LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData.length == 0))">
                                    1
                                </div>
```

Comment: it is not working because we are not repeating the `LT.leaveTrainingData.matrixData` array for the third div